# How to add user defined key and values to array

Tags: javascript, php

I wanted to create a dynamic array with user defined key and value. I have tried my best but I couldn't find a solution.

This is what I have tried:

```
function demo1(form_no) {
  var post_data_array = [];
  var post_data_array2 = [];

  var array1 = ['abc', 'xyz'];

  $.each(array1, function(key, value) {

    var temp_value = $("#" + value + "_" + form_no).val();
    var temp_key = value + "_" + form_no;

    post_data_array.push({
      key2: temp_key,
      value2: temp_value
    });

  });

  $.each(post_data_array, function(index, value) {
    post_data_array2[value.key2] = value.value2;
  });

  .ajax({

    type: "post",
    data: {
      postdata121: post_data_array2
    },
    url: base_url + "/temp_function/" + form_no,
    success: function(result) {
      alert(result);
    }

  });

}
```

But after assigning values to `post_data_array2` I am getting an empty array if I alert the `post_data_array2`.

And even I try to post `post_data_array2` in the ajax function to post data in another page, I am getting postdata empty.

I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Can review your questions, there's some spelling errors making it difficult to understand? Thank you

Comment: JavaScript doesn't strictly have associative arrays, therefore you cannot have custom array keys. When you do `alert(post_data_array2)` you are showing that the array has no items in it (which it doesn't, because you've set its properties rather than adding items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you're saying that you want to use the values in `array1` as keys. To do that, instead of an array `[]`, you use an object `{}`.

This can be accomplished with less code too:

```js
function demo1(form_no) {
  var array1 = ['abc', 'xyz'];
  var data = {};

  $.each(array1, function(key, value) {
    var temp_key = value + "_" + form_no;
    data[temp_key] = $("#" + temp_key).val();
  });
  
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));

  $.ajax({

    type: "post",
    data: {
      postdata121: data
    },
    url: base_url + "/temp_function/" + form_no,
    success: function(result) {
      alert(result);
    }
  });
}

demo1(123);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id=abc_123 value=abcValue>
<input id=xyz_123 value=xyzValue>
```

Now when we loop over the `array1`, we use each member to create a new key/value pair in the `data` object, which gets sent via `$.ajax`.